# can't click and move activity with the menu

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-intent

I make a menu and only have one item with an icon, I intend to make the menu when I click move to another activity.

but with the code like below I can't even move to another activity maybe also can't click it, because there is no animation effect click on the menu,

I use minimum fire level `17` and run this in the `PIE` room, maybe fire level `28`

**Main activity**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.tambah) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, InsertAndViewActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**Menu.xml** from `res > menu > menu.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/tambah"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
    android:orderInCategory="300"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="tambah" />

</menu>
```

in this section I have made activity 3 namely (MainActivity.java, SpalashScreen.java and InsertAndViewActivity.java) as well as the layout for that activity, and I changed AndroidManifest.xml to the following

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".InsertAndViewActivity"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" ></activity>
</application>
```

> I intend to make the menu when I click move to another activity.

Comment: Try changing name menu.xml

Comment: after you click on your menu item, your menu close or not?

Comment: not me because I only included 1 item and it was located on the toolbar with ifRoom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will work for you

Write your menu method's like this,

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.tambah:
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InsertAndViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```